# VBA to loop thru and call next non-blank cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba, list, loops

I'm having trouble trying to find VBA anywhere online that does anything like this, and was hoping someone here may not mind helping me with this.

I have a list, with a header, in column A. The number of non-blank cells in column A will change over time. I would like to enter a value in cell B14 that will match one of the cell values in column A. I am looking for a VBA code that will locate the current value that was entered in B14 from the list in column A, excluding the header (row 1), and then place the NEXT non-blank value of column A into cell B14. Each time the Macro is ran I need the VBA to loop through the list in column A to find the next non-blank value after the list value that is currently in B14, and insert that value in B14.

An example is let's say this is the list in column A:

```
Apples 
Oranges    
Bananas    
[BLANK CELL]    
Peaches    
Blueberries
```

Let's say I currently have `Blueberries` in cell B14. When I run the macro, I want B14 to be replaced with `Apples`, since it's the next non-blank value in the loop.

Thanks a bunch to anyone who is willing to lend a hand with this!

Comment: "I am looking for a VBA code that will locate the current value that was entered in B14 from the list in column A, excluding the header (row 1), and then place the NEXT non-blank value of column A into cell B14." If you are literally looking for that, then your search will probably be in vain. That problem is much too specific to have pre-written code to solve it. The best solution is to write code that does what you want. If you are stuck in writing that code, show your best efforts and ask a more focused question about your code.

Comment: Thanks John. I was looking for something that even just looped thru a range and populated a cell with the next value, and can't even seem to find something that simple. So I can't seem to even get a place to start on the code to show my best efforts, and I sadly don't know how to write loops, or where to start in order to show any current effort. After trying a bunch of a different key words for how to get this thing started, I'm sadly still at "sub nextitem()  /  end sub" so far :|

Comment: @Andrew to give you a starting point: You can use the [Range.Find Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) to find a value in a range and you can use the [Range.Offset Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) to move from the found range. Put in some effort try something and if you get stuck or errors come back with your code and ask a question related to your code. I'm sure people here will kindly help you if you show up with your own code and a good question.